# manipulating CSS using react-ref vs using react setState() vs react-redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-ref

I'm implementing  drag, rotation and resize functionality in react, so I'm changing CSS very frequently, I've three options

1. for each change I can dispatch an action so based on new state render will be called.
2. for each change I can update react state so render will be called,
3. I can change CSS using React-ref.

which will be an efficient way to implement.

Edit:

> efficient in term of performance and implementation.

Comment: Changing DOM directly will always be more efficient. It depends on specific case whether this optimization is required or excessive. Do the benchmarks.

Comment: thanks @estus, sure, actually I'm playing with transform which making more complex to update the translate and rotate value using react-ref. My doubt is if I re-render component using updated style using state, how much extra rendering cost will be there? will be bearable? (coz even after throttling it's calling render very frequently)

Comment: It will possibly be bearable, but this depends on possible bottlenecks (low-end mobiles) and depends on particular transforms. You need to benchmark it yourself and decide.

Comment: I would have used DOM manipulation directly via JS and using transform as much as possible in CSS